# All https sites are redirected to mysite which is hosted on a computer on my network

Tags: ssl, website, https, hosting

I am hosting my website on a computer on my home network. The computer uses Debian Stretch as an operating system. I use dynu.com to post my IP. A while ago I made my website HTTPS using letsencrypt.com and certbot to update. Since then, in every browser on my network, any https site gets redirected to my website. Does anyone know why this is happening?

It's probably a simple setting but is eluding me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please post some configs, look at the apache2 or nginx or whatever webserver you use with priority.
This could also have to do with the network configuration. E.g. what is in your /etc/hosts, /etc/network/interfaces ...

Comment: Sounds like there might be contention between Apache and whatever you're using for proxy or potentially an issue with NAT and DNS.  Start by doing dns lookups on your internal networks ... and then there's always the possibility of routing table weirdness.  Basically, you're on your own until you can figure out the root cause, then the community can help you sort out the configs.

Answer (score -1):

This must be a router problem. Your router us intercepting all requests on port 443 rather then all requests originating on the WAN interface - and forwarding them to your web server.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?